# Getting Values based on Previous and Current Pandas Dataframe for Fanancial Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with following Values

```
DateTime                Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Buy        StopLoss     
2021-09-13 09:15:00     400.00  460.05  352.50  450.40  71675   NaN         NaN
2021-09-13 09:16:00     449.30  456.25  430.00  451.00  68975   500.825     352.50
2021-09-13 09:17:00     451.10  479.50  446.25  448.15  70425   410.375     330.00
2021-09-13 09:18:00     448.65  453.00  425.00  451.75  64800   400.125     367.25 [ Cond ]
2021-09-13 09:19:00     452.35  477.75  446.20  456.45  60400   367.000     320.00 [ Cond ]
```

Now I want to check and add more data in the dataframe with condition that if the current High is above the Buy then additional Buy_Signal will be added in DataFrame with Previous Buy and StopLoss otherwise it will not calculated.

Please Guide How can I achieve it.

The Sample data for the same is as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPwVK.jpg)

Comment: Please include sample data of expected output.  Probably you want to add 2 columns for buy and sell signal ?

Comment: added data for understanding it better. the code requires previous values to be stored and refer and as newbie am not aware how to do it.

Comment: Hello Expert can anybody Help on the request Please?